# Adding leading and trailing space when entering insert mode

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I use vim with ruby. I have a habit of opening and closing brackets when I define new function or a block.

For example I would type:

```
array.map {}_ # _ - cursor position after finishing typing
```

So I am still in **Insert** mode I have a mapping `imap jk <esc>` to get me out to normal mode. Cursor is going back under the closing bracket and I can press **i** to start typing inside the brackets.

My question is how would I go around creating the mapping `<leader>i` that would insert spaces automatically on both sides of the cursor?

```
array.map {}_ # jk<leader>i
array.map { _ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, instead of:

```
array.map { _ }
```

It would be better to have:

```
array.map { _}
```

That is, the cursor is on the second space. Then, whatever you'd type would have a space after it. And a mapping for that would look like:

```
nnoremap <leader>i i  <esc>i
```

- `i`, followed by two spaces
- an `<esc>` to go back to normal, at which point the cursor would be on the second space,
- another `i` to go back to insert mode.

If you have arrow keys working in insert mode, you could use this:

```
nnoremap <leader>i i  <left>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
inoremap <leader>i i<space><space><left>
```